# I installed gcc but when i compile my code there is a problem with clang

Tags: c, macos, gcc, import, clang

I installed gcc on my mac os but i don't it doesn't work due to a clang module, i used gcc my_program.c -Wall -o prog.

I have tried to reinstall and to follow some answers online , it doesn't work

When i compiled i got this in my terminal :

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_omp_get_thread_num", referenced from:
      _tri_pair_impair in tri_pair_impair-a7c555.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I except to be able to compile my C code with gcc to do parallel computing

Comment: Did you use `-v` to see invocation?

Comment: If you're using Xcode, `gcc` is just an alias for Apple's version of clang. It's stupid and annoying. If you want to use an actual gcc instead of clang, you have it install it separately - maybe through homebrew or the like?

Comment: Though with either compiler if you're using OpenMP you have to tell it that with the appropriate command line argument.

Comment: that error message(s) is from the linker.  That means the command line is missing the necessary library information.   It does look like the appropriate header file(s) was visible to the compiler.